# Indefinite integration of derivative of distributions

Tags: derivatives, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Working over the real line, I am interested in the integral of the form
$$
I := \int_a^b dx \int_a^x dy f(y) \delta'(y),
$$
where $a < 0 < b < \infty$, $f$ is some smooth test function with compact support such that $(a,b) \subset supp(f)$, and $\delta$ is the usual Dirac delta "function".

At first, when attempting to evaluate this integral, I naively used that $\delta'(f) = -\delta(f')=-f'(0)$ so that the above integral would evaluate to $(a-b) f'(0)$.
However, looking at it more closely, the result $\delta'(f) = -\delta(f')$ which can be attributed to "integration by parts", is really only working if the integration is actually over the support of $f$. This is not the case for the first integral.

Instead, I modified the relation such that
$$
I = \int_a^b dx \left( [f(y) \delta(y)]_a^x - \int_a^x dyf'(y) \delta(y) \right)= \int_a^b dx \left(f(x) \delta(x) - f'(0) \right) = f(0) + (a-b) f'(0).
$$
Is this the correct way to do this? I simply generalised the "integration by parts" rule. Is there a rigourous explanation why this is the correct answer?

Comment: The Dirac Delta is NOT a function, it is a distribution.  And the object written with an integral sign is NOT an integral, it is a linear functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global strategy is good, but there are some caveat. The integration by parts is correct, but the next steps should be :
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
I 
  &=&\displaystyle
  \int_a^b\mathrm{d}x \left( [f(y) \delta(y)]_a^x - \int_a^x\mathrm{d}y\,f'(y) \delta(y) \right) \\
  &=&\displaystyle
  \int_a^b\mathrm{d}x \left( f(x)\delta(x) - f'(0)H(x) \right) \\
  &=&\displaystyle
  f(0) - f'(0) \int_a^b H(x) \,\mathrm{d}x \\
  &=&\displaystyle
  f(0) - f'(0)[xH(x)]_a^b \\
  &=&\displaystyle
  f(0) - bf'(0) \color{white}{\frac{1}{1}}
\end{array}
$$
where $H$ is the Heaviside function, which plays the role of Dirac delta's antiderivative. Indeed, since $x\in(a,b)$ can be negative, the condition $0\in(a,x)$ is not guaranteed, that is why
$$
\int_a^x f'(y)\delta(y) \,\mathrm{d}y \equiv f'(0) \int_a^x \delta(y) \,\mathrm{d}y = f'(0) [H(y)]_a^x = f'(0)H(x) \neq f'(0).
$$

Comment: Why do you think your first two lines are allowed?

Answer (score 1):

$I := \int_a^b dx \int_a^x dy f(y) \delta'(y)$  is ill-defined because $\int_a^0 dy f(y) \delta'(y)$ is ill-defined.

Abezhiko's integration by part answer is what you get when interpreting it as

$$I := \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_a^b dx \int_a^x dy f(y) h_n'(y)$$
where $h_n(y)=n e^{-\pi n^2 y^2}$ converges to $\delta$ in the sense of distributions.

Comment: (+1) for addressing the abuse of notation and meaninglessness of the object $\int_a^x f(y)\delta'(y)\,dy$

Comment: @MarkViola I am not very knowlegable on distributions. Could you tell me what would be a rigourous way of writing this?

Comment: $ \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_a^b dx \int_a^x dy f(y) h_n'(y)$ @Patrick.B

Comment: Having said that, this kind of limit is implicit with distributions such as Dirac delta, since the whole purpose of distribution theory is the justification of such abuse of notation.